Troubleshooting and fixing laptop battery charging issues
My HP laptop battery does not charge. It only shows 0% available all the time. The following is what I tried to do so far:

I installed a BIOS update.
I removed the battery from the laptop and opened it and here's what I found so far:

The multimeter shows power on the cells as indicated in the images below:


There's a reading on the VH and VL located on the circuit board:


There's a reading on the VM and VL:


There's a reading on the VH and VM:



No reading on the pins


There might have been a small black component on the board (something fell out when I opened the battery case but I can't find it).




I don't know much about electronics and electronic engineering, but if you can give me any advice on how to fix my battery I would be grateful.

Update: I'm answering the questions in the comments.
My laptop, model HP Notebook (15-ay031ni), is older than 4 years. I had an experiment where I kept the charger on for a few months to see if the battery would last. I guess my experiment broke it. Is it possible that the "small black component" is causing the current from flowing? I don't think the cells are broken. I think the issue might be on the circuit board. Because there is no current on the pins, I think it might be the missing black components that is causing the issue. Do you agree? How do I fix it? Can I use ones from another battery?
Find below a picture of the circuit board.


What laptop model? How old is it? Batteries fail and die, often far sooner than the rest of the laptop. What led up to this failure? Was it a sudden failure, working fine one day and not at all the next, or did it slowly lose ability to hold a charge, or something else? Please EDIT your post to add this and any other information helpful to our understanding your situation.

Batteries die. Replace it. Just because you have some voltages at particular points doesn't mean that the battery is healthy. It might have a whisker internally that makes contact when warm or current is drawn and so the laptop can't draw current from it.  Batteries are not like other solid electronic parts, they are a constantly deteriorating chemical reaction and if the battery is more than 4 years old and starts to have problems then the best you can do is send it to a recycling place and buy a new one.

It's older than 4 years. I had an experiment where I kept the charger on for a few months to see if the battery would last. I guess my experiment broke it. I was just wondering, since the cells are showing +14 volts if there's a chance I could fix it.

The "small black component" could be a diode or fuse, and we can't guess without knowing exact make and model and someone with electronics knowledge would need the battery in front of them and even if the problem is that component it would require more than a multimeter to replace. Either take it to a repair shop or buy a new one, though a repair shop would likely charge more than the cost of a new battery.

Batteries, even internal batteries, are relatively simple to replace. Purchase a new battery if your laptop is otherwise working fine. There are limits on the value of support we can offer here for hardware issues, but, in this case at least, it is simple: replace your battery.

I was hoping for a engineering solution. Obviously, my first thought was to replace it. That's troubleshooting 101.

Well, batteries are gloriously inflammable. Replacing batteries are better than replacing your home and its contents.

Understood. I'll through it away!

Your battery has failed. Replace it.
You can purchase OEM replacement batteries easily enough, and your laptop has a very easy-to-replace battery.
While there is a small chance the issue is not with the battery, for cost, simplicity, and low risk of other issues likely to occur as a result of the service, replacing the battery is the correct course of action given what you have told us.

I'll accept your answer if you answer me this one. Is electronic engineering questions outside the scope of this forum?

4 years is pretty old for a battery. Many batteries last longer than that, even given the same usage patterns you describe, but plenty do not. Batteries are often warrantied for as little as 6 or 9 months past their manufacture date, NOT the computer ship date. The proper path for computer repair is to start with the obvious, weighted for ease and cost of replacement. The battery is the thing to start with. There is already an Electrical Engineering sister site, and you're free to present your question there. They may approach the issue in a way more to your liking.

Thanks @music2myear for refering me. I'll try over there.
